# Entire (completely) overwrite CSS styles

Tags: html, css

How can I overwrite an entire CSS style for a class, id or other CSS selector?

For example:

If in `styles1.css` I have:

```
/* also, this file contains a lot of styles used on other pages */

.one-great-class {
    background: white
    ...
    /* a lot of properties */
}
```

... and in `styles2.css` (that is used only in one web page) I want to overwrite the class `one-great-class` **completely** what have I do to write?

```
.one-great-class {
    /* Is possible that a line of code to delete all styles from this class? */
}
```

Comment: Why just not remove the style from the original CSS?

Comment: @kba you cant necessarily do that. What if the css is part of a 3rd party library ?

Comment: Supose that first file contains a lot of styles, and they are used on other pages. And in a single page I want to use the second file.

Comment: @karthikr: Then edit the 3rd part library to use your own styles. John: Why not use a different class name on the other page, then?

Comment: @kba Really ? That is scary dude. If you update the library your changes are gone.. Bad idea

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not possible in CSS at the moment.

But there may eventually be a property that does this: [`all`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-cascade/)

It can take three values:

`initial` | `inherited` | `unset`

Taken from the [Cascading and Inheritance Module](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-cascade/):

*"For example, if an author specifies all: initial on an element it will block all inheritance and reset all properties, as if no rules appeared in the author, user, or user-agent levels of the cascade. "*

According to the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/all) as of June 2017, `all` is currently supported by Chrome, Firefox/Mobile, and Opera. Safari supports only the CSS4 value `revert`, which is not supported by the other browsers.

```
  .one-great-class {
      border-radius: 50% 35% / 20% 25% 60%;
      color: red;
      font: 12px/14px Arial, serif;
      height: 20em;
      width: 20em;
    /*... etc. */
  }

  .one-great-class {
      all: initial;
  }
```

Comment: Note that this will also override any property set by other rule-sets (except those which appear further down the cascade).

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately it doesn't work. See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dfn7G/1/). It has to be the same thing if the first line from CSS is commented or not. Am I correct?

Comment: Also keep in mind I said that the `all` property is not something supported widely right now .. the module is still in working draft status

Comment: @Adrift, yes. It was my mistake. Look again [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Dfn7G/2/). I want to overwrite the `.btn` class completely. So, it has to remain a simple `div`, hasn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Tested to work with IE9, Chrome and Opera. I had a problem with this when I wrote it, so decided that rather than changing existing rules, that I'd just append a new rule after the existing ones. From memory, the problem was with the default browser found in Android 2.3

Altering an existing rule seemed to be a better(cleaner) solution, though appending new rules ultimately proved to be chosen path. (I was changing background images by creating images with a canvas and then setting the background-image property. The images could be quite large, hence the preference for update)

**Function**

```
function replaceRuleAttrib(ruleSelector, attribText, newValue)
{
    var nSheets, nRules, sheetNum, curSheet, curStyle, curAttrib;
    var nSheets = document.styleSheets.length;

    if (nSheets == 0)
        document.head.appendChild(document.createElement('style'));
    else
    for (sheetNum = 0; sheetNum<nSheets; sheetNum++)
    {   
        curSheet = document.styleSheets[sheetNum];
        nRules = curSheet.cssRules.length;
        for (ruleNum=0; ruleNum<nRules; ruleNum++)
        {
            curRule = curSheet.cssRules[ruleNum];
            if (curRule.selectorText == ruleSelector)
            {
                for (styleI=0; styleI<curRule.style.length; styleI++)
                {
                    styleName = curRule.style[styleI];
                    styleVal = curRule.style[styleName];
                    if (styleName == attribText)
                    {
                        curRule.style[styleName] = newValue;
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    document.styleSheets[0].insertRule( ruleSelector+'{' + attribText + ": " + newValue + "; }",  0);   
}
```

**Sample CSS (before)**

```
<style>
h1
{
    color: red;
}
</style>
```

**Usage:**

```
function onHeadingClick()
{
    replaceRuleAttrib('h1', 'color', 'green');
}
```

**Sample CSS (after)**

```
<style>
h1
{
    color: green;
}
</style>
```

Comment: I wouldn't use Javascript. Only CSS.

Comment: No, I don't think it's ideal either. It is however, the _only_ way to overwrite a css style (which was after all, what you asked for). All other solutions involve overriding it (but leaving it there intact, and adding another style after the offending one) :-)

Answer (score -1):

Browser will apply css that come last.

```
.class {
font-size: 16px;
font-size: 14px;
}
```

The class will get font-size value 14px.

You can decleare a css as final.

```
.class {
font-size: 14px !important;
}
```

no genarel css rule can alter it.

Browser uses this method to give priority
inline < embeded < external < user-agent.

If you think you need more controll on css then use javascript to directly modfy dom.