# How to use "all" property in CSS

Tags: html, css

How is the `all` property used in CSS?

This question is related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15953876/entire-completely-overwrite-css-styles).

According to [this](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-cascade/#all-shorthand):

> The ‘all’ property is a shorthand that resets all CSS properties.

```
Name:           all
Value:          initial | inherit | default
Initial:        See individual properties
Applies to:     See individual properties
Inherited:      See individual properties
Percentages:    See individual properties
Media:          See individual properties
Computed value: See individual properties
Animatable:     See individual properties
```

So, it has to reset CSS properties for a selector.

This means, for example, that if we import Twitter Bootstrap and add the style below, the `.btn` class has to be reseted:

```
.btn {
    all: default;
}
```

This doesn't happen. See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dfn7G/2/).

Am I correct? Isn't this implemented in web browsers?

Comment: Note that the `default` keyword no longer exists in the current revision of the spec as of 2014. Presumably this was because it was difficult to fully define, or implement. There is currently no proposed way to reset properties of an element to their browser defaults.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The W3C specification you linked to says it's currently in "Working Draft" stage. Also, there's no mention of the `all` property on CanIUse.com, so I think it's safe to say it's experimental.

You might want to try `-webkit-all` or `-moz-all`.

Y'know, reading the spec for this feature, it feels like a hack. If you design your style cascade appropriately there shouldn't be a need for this property.

Comment: Thank you. But `-webkit-all` and `-moz-all` also don't work. Is there any another solution?

Comment: If they don't work then it probably isn't implemented. Why do you want to use this feature?

Comment: @Dai, it's a feature that would be useful to revert form elements to their original browser-defined styles.

Comment: This property was introduced as less of a crutch for poorly-written code and more of a way to deal with third-party CSS that the author has no control over. This is mentioned in the spec.

Answer (score 2):

Right now I believe only Firefox supports `all` ([as of version 27](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-cascade/#all-shorthand)). You can use the `all` property (e.g. all: unset;) to apply the value to every property (except direction and unicode-bidi).

Comment: Can you add a demo jsfiddle?

Comment: Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/MattSmith/LgSzP/. View this in latest version of Firefox. The first example of the `<input range>` element is styled with the browsers user agent stylesheet. The second element has been reset. Here's more on the values for the `all` property: http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-cascade/#all-shorthand

Comment: +1, Interesting! Can you explain me how to unset only the properties set by me before (I don't want to unset the browser's default settings)? See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/LgSzP/2/).

Comment: I _think_ you'd need to unset first (e.g., button {all:unset}) then add your selector rule to style (e.g., button { }). I'm not certain about targeting only certain properties of a rule. More [reading](http://mcc.id.au/blog/2013/10/all-unset).

Comment: @MattSmith Also, the 'default' mentioned in the question is currently implemented as 'initial' in FF27.

You can target only certain properties just fine with `css-wide` keywords. I [blogged](http://www.geedew.com/2014/02/20/css-wide-keywords-and-all-selectors/) about it. You can also style, set to `initial`, and then style differently.

Comment: @geedew: `default` and `initial` are two different things - `default`, which has now been dropped from the spec, refers to browser defaults, and `initial` refers to spec-defined initial values that do not vary per element.

Answer (score 0):

See this pen in latest FireFox: http://codepen.io/tomliv/pen/AejFH

There are 3 inputs in the grey area (really!).

This is not what I was expecting, but maybe setting `all` to `initial` will be more what you need?

Comment: Is this supposed to be an answer?

Comment: It was an attempt to display the difference between `initial` and `unset` which was mentioned in another comment.

Answer (score -4):

There really is no **default** value for every property - at least one that is consistent across all browsers.

That's really where a CSS reset comes in. I'd recommend looking at Eric Meyer's CSS reset: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/. Typically, these types of resets are used to reduce browser inconsistencies.

If you're looking to apply something to all *elements* (you'll still need to individually list each property), use

```
* { /* Universal Selector */ }
```

Using a reset stylesheet or some CSS framework like bootstrap is probably a better solution for both normalizing your CSS and cross browser consistency.

Comment: I don't want to apply same style to all elements. I want to reset all CSS properties for a selector/element.

Comment: As I've tried to explain, there is no cross-browser **default** value. You need to be more explicit when resetting your properties.

Comment: I would like to mention that using `*` isn't just "poor css design" it's a severe Performance penalty on rendering the page. I cannot recommend using it; at any time.

Comment: @geedew - quoted from [an article written by Paul Irish](http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/) where he _recommends_ using the `*` selector, "Apparently you’ve heard its slow. Firstly, it’s not. It is as fast as h1 as a selector."

Comment: @Wex While I respect Paul Irish's opinion, you're taking his point out of context. Obviously, it's not naturally slow. If it were the only selector on the page it would be very fast. However, in real use, on a real web-app, it's incredibly slow. To the other extreme, in some situations, a `*` selector can be 25% of the entire render time. While the render time might only be 1ms, it's still slow, relative to the entire set of code. TYL: quotes mean nothing; especially from advocates.